# What is the fastest way of determining rank of a new element in the existing numpy array without computing ranks for the whole array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Given an array of numbers `A` and some decimal number `X`, I would like to know the rank of `X` in `A`, and the straightforward way of doing this is to append a new number into the initial array, run `rankdata` on it and pick the last element, like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import rankdata

A = np.array([33.25, 40.16, 18.22, 96.34, 71.15, 48.12, 52.41, 83.11, 12.22])
X = 54.17
B = np.append(A, X)
ranks = rankdata(-B) # reverse an array so that the largest value will have rank 1
rank = int(ranks[-1])
```

Even though it produces the correct result, in order to run it often and on large arrays, it would be useful to obtain it without sorting the whole array.

With that in mind I wonder whether there is a `numpy` or `scipy` idiom of doing it faster.

Comment: `np.searchsorted(A, X) + 1`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest It assumes that the array is sorted, which is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use np.sum with a comparison to X before (or even without) appending the value in a new array.

Use the comparison that corresponds to the order of ranking you are looking for:

```
rank = np.sum(A<X)+1  # 7  (i.e. X is 7th smallest)

rank = np.sum(A>X)+1   # 4 (i.e. X is 4th largest)
```

Comment: This is the best solution so far, on an array I tried it on it is 9.5 times faster than my naïve solution in the original post and 1.2 times faster than using `argsort`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you would like to determine the rank of new items "often and on large arrays", you'll need a sorted list. Hence, you might as well keep the items in a sorted data structure. Some of the data structures with the best complexity for this (O(n log(n))) would be B-trees and heaps.

Comment: I need to find a rank of a new element in a different array every time, rather than in the same array repeatedly, so that keeping arrays in sorted order doesn't seem like the solution.

Comment: Got it. In that case what Alain T. proposes in his answer looks like the right way to me.

Comment: I agree, it is likely to be the best possible solution.